# Do equivalent Cayley Tables imply isomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, cayley-table

It works for $\Bbb{Z}_2$ under addition and $\{1,-1\}$ under multiplication, but I can't think of any counterexamples. I would think that it's enough, but are there exceptions to this?

Comment: A Cayley table completely defines the structure of a finite group, so yes equivalent tables implies isomorphism (assuming you mean something sensible by equivalent).

Comment: By equivalent I meant replacing the elements of one with corresponding elements of the second creates a table identical to the second. Which is what I assume you meant, too.

Comment: Yes. That certainly implies isomorphism because you have a bijection $f$ such that $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$ which is what you need for isomorphism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose the two Cayley tables are identical in the sense that whenever the first table has a symbol $a$ the second table has the symbol $a'$ (and conversely).  Then the map $\phi: a \mapsto a'$ is a group isomorphism.  For it is clear $\phi$ is bijective.  And $\phi$ respects the group operation because if $ab=c$ in the first table, then $a'b'=c'$ in the second table, which can be rewritten as $\phi(a) \phi(b) = \phi(c)$.